# How to programatically generate n UILabels and add to View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am newbie in iOS Development.

My goal is to:

1. Generate N UILabels

   UILabel *label0 = [[UILabel alloc]init]

   UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]init]

   ...

   UILabel *label n = [[UILabel alloc]init];
2. Add each UILabel to View using addSubView

To generate N UILabels (please correct me if I am doing in wrong way), I declared `NSMutableDictionay` in `viewcontroller.h`

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableDictionary *uiLabelsDictionary;
```

In viewcontroller.m

```
self.uiLabelsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

int yOffset = 40;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    yOffset = yOffset+40;
    [self.uiLabelsDictionary setObject:[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yOffset, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width)] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%d",i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",self.uiLabelsDictionary);
```

I am stuck on next step. How do I read each UILabel stored in the dictionary as UILabel and add to view?

Dictionary Output

```
label0 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbd08ba0; frame = (10 80; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x608000090680>>";
label1 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc0f7b0; frame = (10 120; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008e240>>";
label2 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc15570; frame = (10 160; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008e4c0>>";
label3 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc159a0; frame = (10 200; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008e5b0>>";
 label4 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc15c30; frame = (10 240; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008e790>>";
 label5 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc16040; frame = (10 280; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008ebf0>>";
 label6 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc162d0; frame = (10 320; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008ef10>>";
 label7 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc16560; frame = (10 360; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008e510>>";
 label8 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc167f0; frame = (10 400; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008ec40>>";
 label9 = "<UILabel: 0x7f83dbc16a80; frame = (10 440; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x60800008f460>>";
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/users/680925/perception

Comment: The question you might want to ask yourself is 'am I doing the right thing'. If you're trying to generate that many labels, you might want them to be in a UITableView or UICollectionView.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh Thankyou for reply . You are right about using in UITableVIew or Collection View . what i meant by question was generating n UIViewobject in combination with NSDictionary is the right way

Comment: Using a dictionary is a poor choice here. Things would be much simpler using an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for reply.  Is it possible to map each uilabel in NSMutableArrray like in NSDictionary Output  label0 = "<UILabel: 0x7fc91670b2f0; frame = (10 80; 320 320); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x600000095630>>";

Comment: What about using `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` Instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *labels;
```

and

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80+i*40, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width)];
    [self.view addSubview:label]; // Add the label to the view
    [labels addObject:label]; // Keep track of the labels
}
self.labels = labels;

NSLog(@"%@", labels);

// Later on...
UILabel *label0 = self.labels[0]; // Get a reference to label 0
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply . Is it possible to dynamically generate UILabel *label0,UILabel *label1,UILabel *label2..

Comment: You have exactly that inside the array; label[0], label[1], label[2] ...

Comment: UILabel *label0 = self.label[i] , right side ok , what about left side , is it possible to dynamically generate UILabel label1,UILabel label2,...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, maybe ask this as a new question.

Comment: In the last part of your answer you specified UILabel *label0 = self.label[0]. i have to manually do 10 times for 10 labels. is it possible to make it dynamic by a for loop with count of "labels"

Comment: You can't dynamically create variable names in objective-c (at least not without messing about with the runtime - which you don't want to do) but why do you need label0 anyway, you have label[0] just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this --

```
int yOffset = 40;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    yOffset = yOffset+40;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yOffset, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
    label.tag = i; //You can access any label by using tag
    [self.view addSubView:label];
}
```

===================

And If you want to scroll the page then simply use UITableView

Comment: Thankyou for reply. i am newbie , Is it possible to UILabel *label1,UILabel *label2 programmattcally . Is this can only be achieved by tags

Comment: My second doubt is assigning reference to *label variable 10 times . will it result *label only point to last UIlabel?

Comment: No, it will create 10 different objects of UIlabel. And you can access any of them by using
" UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [self.view viewWithTag:1]; "

Comment: Will ARC deallocate other 9 objects automatically as it does not have reference?

Comment: No, they will not be dellocated. They will be destroy with the ViewController